# Newcommand not working in Lyx

Tags: macros, lyx

I am using lyx for writing a latex document. The following is the preamble in `Document > Settings`:

```
\usepackage{fullpage}

\newcommand{\authnote}[1]{\textcolor{green}{\small {\textbf{(Auth:} #1\textbf{) }}}}

\usepackage{hyperref}
```

And the document contains only 1 line:

In the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> environment: `\authnote{aa}`

It is giving an undefined control sequence error. What's the problem?

Comment: Which sequence is reported is undefined?  You use `\textcolor` so you need to load a package that defines that command, e.g. `color` or `xcolor`

Comment: \usepackage{xcolor} worked! Thanks! Can you put the comment as an answer? I can accept it then.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by the comment below the question

Comment: @StefanPinnow I would understand that it is off-topic as a package was missing. But answered in comments doesn't make something off-topic right? Also as the question has a real answer. You could also find a duplicate, but to me an undefined control sequesnce would be off-topic, as there are indefinitely many typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command contains the macro `\textcolor`.  This is not part of standard LaTeX, so you need to load an appropriate package.  The two main choices are the `color` package from the `graphics` bundle, and the `xcolor` package which is an extension with many more predefined color names and access to different color models.  So I suggest you add

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

to your document.